# Valores Numéricos em variavel de sessão php

Tags: php

as variaveis de sessão no php só adotam valores string ou consigo passar valores numericos para este tipo de variavel? 
Tenho um form com os campos login, senha e um select option com um valor numerico. consigo passar o valor deste select para uma variavel de sessão?

Answer (score 2):

Em sessão você consegue passar quase tudo, ou seja você pode adicionar:

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['int'] = 1;
$_SESSION['float'] = 0.1;
$_SESSION['string'] = 'str';
$_SESSION['object'] = new FooBar;
```

Claro que no caso de uma classe só os valores serão salvos na sessão, quando for tentar acessar na próxima página, no entanto se a classe existir será possivel usar como se tivesse instanciado.

**O único** que não pode ser adicionado é o `Closure`, se fizer isto:

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['closure'] = function () {};
```

Ou isto:

```
session_start();

$foo = array(
    'foo' => 1,
    'baz' => 'str',
    'bar' => function () {}
);

$_SESSION['closure'] = $foo;
```

Vai causar um erro como:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed' in [no active file]:0 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in [no active file] on line 0

### Sobre o formulário

> Tenho um form com os campos login, senha e um select option com um valor numerico. consigo passar o valor deste select para uma variavel de sessão?

Dados passados via HTTP sempre serão "string" quando recebidos no PHP, se deseja converte-los pode usar coisas como:

- `$x = intval($_POST['...'])` ou `$x = (int) $_POST['...'];`,
- `$x = (float) $_POST['...'];`

E depois gravar na sessão

Comment: Uma observação seria se utilizar JSON, exemplo `json_decode($_POST['json'])` manterá o tipo enviado, sem conversão adicional.